# Sprite sheet images not showing

Tags: html, css, sprite-sheet

I'm using a sprite sheet for my social media buttons but I can't get the images to show...?

Is there anything glaringly obvious I'm doing wrong?

```css
.socials {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#menubar_top .socials .facebook .fb {
  background: url(images/social-media-logo-set1.png) 0px 0px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#menubar_top .socials .facebook .fb:hover {
  background: url(images/social-media-logo-set1.png) 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
  <a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com"><img class="fb" src="images/placeholders/40x40.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is image:
[socials sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCI4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Below an example using the image you provided.

- On hover, you need to change the background position for the sprite
- The sprite itself, does not contain the correct sizes for the social images

```css
.socials .facebook {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCI4.png) -18px -13px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
}

.socials .facebook:hover {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCI4.png) -18px -105px;
}
```

```html
<div class="socials">
  <a class="facebook" target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com"></a>
</div>
```